# Regular expression works different in preg_match function

Tags: php, regex

I want to make a regex, that matches letters from all alphabets and special characters, and ignores symbols like `✪❀✱↴♜` and so on.

My regular expression looks like:
`/^([\p{L}0-9~!@#$%^&*_\-+='|{}\(\)\[\]:;"<>,.?\/\\\s])+$/i`.
Problem is - it works perfectly in regex online tester, but somehow fails in PHP code for non latin strings like `ǺǻαάǠẮắẰằẳẴẵÄªäÅÀÁÂåãâàáÃᗩ`:

```
$text = 'ǺǻαάǠẮắẰằẳẴẵÄªäÅÀÁÂåãâàáÃᗩ';
if(preg_match("/^([\p{L}0-9~!@#$%^&*_\-+='|{}\(\)\[\]:;\"<>,.?\/\\\s])+$/i", $text)){
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

I have also tried another regex: `/[\p{L}0-9~!@#$%^&*_\-+='|{}\(\)\[\]:;"<>,.?\/\\\s]+/i`. It also works fine in regex tester, but in preg match function it matches almost everything. Does anyone know why those regular expressions behave so in preg_match function?

Comment: Use `/u` modifier.

Comment: Add delimiters at the start of your pattern: #/^([\p{L}0-9~!@#$%^&*_\-+='|{}\(\)\[\]:;\"<>,.?\/\\\s])+$#, also, I dont think that you can add flags with the pattern, they should be passed as a separate parametar in preg_match function